# How to extend behavior of a class object for every method?

Tags: java

Let say, if I pass an object of a Map to the method `public Map needExtendedLogs(Map m) {}`.
The returned object should be available with extended behavior of logging and whenever I call any method of Map on that object, in addition to the operation some log should be print on the console.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Extender {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
           m.put("key1", "val1");
           m.put("key2", "val2");
           m.put("key3", "val3");

           m.get("key1");

           m = needExtendedLogs(m);

           m.get("key2"); // this should print log
           m.put("key4", "val4"); // this should print log
       }

       public static Map needExtendedLogs(Map m) {

              // TODO
           return m;
       }
    }
```

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy wouldn't decorator solve this?

Answer (score 1):

[AspectJ](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html) allows you to do this using aspect-oriented programming in Java.

As a simplification, it will allow you to hook any method calls and execute code before or after these method calls.

Comment: I like this idea. It also allows for easy removal of these hooks without the need of massive reworks.

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of it actually. Note that the subclassing does not need massive rework, you just need to stick to the interface and use dependency injection, it should be easy to substitute one implementation by another one. However I think it's tedious to override every method in Map interface just to add some logging.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple approach for something like that would be to extend an existing implementation of the `Map` interface. For example this could be what you need:

```
public class LoggingMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        System.out.printf("About to put() key:: %s - value:: %s", key, value);
    return super.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
    System.out.printf("About to get() key:: %s", key);
    V value = super.get(key);
    System.out.printf("Got value:: %s for key:: %s", value, key);
    return value;
    }

}
```

Not really sure why you need to do that and in fact I would advise against extending classes like (i.e composition vs inheritance) but if this what you need to do, the above example is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Log> m = new HashMap<String, Log>();
        m.put("key1", new Log("va11"));
        m.put("key2", new Log("va11"));
        m.put("key3", new Log("va11"));

        m.get("key2").printLog(); // this should print log
        m.put("key4", new Log("va11")); // this should print log
    }

}

 class Log{
    private String log;

    Log(String log){
        this.log = log;
    }

    public void printLog(){
        System.out.println(log);
    }
 }
```

I don't understand exactly what you meant.